# Layout in ViewPager being replaced

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-xml

I have a `ViewPager` layout like the one below. However, the `LinearLayout` within the `ViewPager` disappears and is replaced by the content I'm loading into the `ViewPager`.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:pstsTabTextAlpha="150"
        app:pstsIndicatorHeight="3dp"
        app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
        app:pstsUnderlineHeight="0dp"
        app:pstsTabTextSize="14dp"
        />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_image"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements FirstFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        SecondFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        ThirdFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize the ViewPager and set an adapter
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        // Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
        PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_group, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri){
        //
    }

    private class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private final String[] TITLES = {"First", "Second", "Third"};

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return TITLES[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return TITLES.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new FirstFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new SecondFragment();
                case 2:
                    return new ThirdFragment();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**FirstFragment.java**

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    String BASE_URL = "http://www.example.com/api";

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FirstFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FirstFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public FirstFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        final ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_posts);

        final ArrayList<Post> postArray = new ArrayList<Post>();

        // REST API
        final RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
                .build();

        final ApiEndpointInterface apiService = restAdapter.create(ApiEndpointInterface.class);

        apiService.getData(1, new Callback<PostData>() {

            @Override
            public void success(PostData postData, Response response) {
                final PostAdapter adapter = new PostAdapter(getActivity(), postArray);
                postArray.addAll(postData.getData());
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                retrofitError.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    class Deserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Post> {
        @Override
        public Post deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc)
                throws JsonParseException {
            // Get the "content" element from the parsed JSON
            JsonElement content = je.getAsJsonObject().get("data");

            // Deserialize it. You use a new instance of Gson to avoid infinite recursion
            // to this deserializer
            return new Gson().fromJson(content, Post.class);

        }
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

**fragment_first.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.project.app.FirstFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_posts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="@null" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Why is it replacing everything in the `ViewPager`? How can I instead *append* the data to the `ViewPager`, such that the data goes below the layout in the `ViewPager`?

Answer (score 0):

you should **include this components** in **Fragment layout**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.project.app.FirstFragment">
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_image"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_posts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="@null" />

</LinearLayout>
```

or place them under ViewPager like this

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:pstsTabTextAlpha="150"
        app:pstsIndicatorHeight="3dp"
        app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
        app:pstsUnderlineHeight="0dp"
        app:pstsTabTextSize="14dp"
        />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs">



    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
 <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_image"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Those components need to be above the ViewPager, but if I do that, only the ViewPager is scrollable, not the whole page.

Comment: yes, becouse they are static, so you have to include them in fragment layout

Comment: But again, if I put the components above the ViewPager, only the ViewPager is scrollable. I need the whole screen to be scrollable.

Comment: I tried your edit but now the data isn't being loaded into the ViewPager.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that... The viewpager will always do this.. yiu may need to put the layouts outside the viewpager.. in a way the makes user feel they are inside...

Comment: If I put the layout outside the ViewPager, it works, but the problem is that only the ViewPager is scrollable and not the whole page.

Comment: So you have to put them in the fragments layout... do you have to update the data from the activity ?

Comment: I tried putting the layout in the fragments layout but the data isn't loading into the ViewPager anymore.

Comment: And this is what you have to fix.. i can help .show me the code... If you want the views to scroll with the viewpager.. there is no way out.. you have to add them to the fragment layouts..

Comment: The code is in the question. All I did was move the layout to the fragments layout.

Comment: In the first fragment layout.. make the linear layout vertical.. by default its horizontal

Comment: Okay, it is loading the data fine now, but still only the ViewPager is scrollable, not the whole page.

Comment: Every thing inside the pager is scrollable ?... What full page?! The one of the activity you mean ?

Comment: The layout I added to the fragment layout is `120dp` high so it takes up a lot of the screen. The rest of the screen is the ViewPager. Only the ViewPager part of the screen is scrollable and not the rest. I need the whole page to scroll, not just the ViewPager. Here is a picture to make it clear: http://i.imgur.com/Vhg116L.png. I need the whole screen scrollable.

Comment: The fragment layout is in the viewpager.. but i gues you are talking about the list view...you want all the page to be scrollable.. not just the listview.. in the first fragment layout.. you can use scroll view and put the linear layout inside it... But then you will have list view inside scroll view.. which is not good ... Any way try it

Comment: It scrolls whole page but it's buggy. It only scrolls down for a little bit and not all the way to the bottom of the viewpager.

Comment: Its because ypu have list view which is scrollable.. you should never have two views inside each other both scroll with same directions.. if you persist.. you shouldn't use listview... You can use linearlayout... And fill it with all the items of the listview..You can use tha same adapter...